# RoboMongo find certain documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

In my collection `Person` I have many people named Mike.
Is there a way I can find all the people with first name Mike?
Currently I am only able to find one person at a time using the entire name.

```
db.getCollection('Person').find({'name':'Mike Jones'})
db.getCollection('Person').find({'name':'Mike Woo'})
db.getCollection('Person').find({'name':'Mike Smith'})
```

I tried doing something like:

```
db.getCollection('Person').find({'name':'Mike '+ *})
```

Very new to MongoDb thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
db.getCollection('Person').find({'name':/^Mike/})
```

Strictly speaking that is using a left anchored regular expression to look for all strings that start with "Mike", you can make it more selective if you wish.